# How to handle empty strings like you can nulls with isnull()?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have small problem parsing strings in SQL Server.

I have a table like this:

**emp**

```
sn | code      | sal
1  | 1100F-    | 100
2  |           | 200
3  | 97535-GO  | 300
4  | 97530-GO  | 300
5  |           | 600
6  | 9830      |200
```

Based on this table data I'd like to output the results like below:

```
sn | code     | Changed  | sal
1  | 1100F    | NA       | 100
2  | 0        | NA       | 200
3  | 97535    | GO       | 300
4  | 97530    | GO       |300
5  | 0        | NA       |600
6  |9830      | NA       |200
```

The Changed column should contain everything from the code column after the `-`, there is nothing after the `-` or there is no `-`, I should use `NA`.

My current code is:

```
select 
   sn,
   code,
   sal case WHEN CHARINDEX('-',code)>0  
     THEN SUBSTRING(code,CHARINDEX('-',code)+1,len(code)) 
     ELSE 'NA' END changed
from emp
```

The problem I am having is that for the first row, I am getting an empty string instead of `NA`, can someone help change it so that if there is a `-` without a code, it displays `NA`?

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want, but I'm not entirely happy with it because of the duplication:

```
select 
sn,
case when charindex('-', code) > 0
    then 
        case substring(code, charindex('-', code) + 1, len(code))
        when '' then 'NA'
        else substring(code, charindex('-', code) + 1, len(code))
        end
    else 'NA'
    end
from emp
```

But the extra nested case will ensure that empty codes have 'NA'.

It might make more sense to define a scalar value function for this and use some variables instead, like so:

```
create function GetChanged(@code varchar(10)) returns varchar(10)
as
begin 
    declare @result varchar(10) = 'NA';
    declare @dashIndex int = charindex('-', @code);
    if (@dashIndex > 0)
    begin
        declare @changed varchar(10) = substring(@code, @dashIndex + 1, len(@code))
        if (@changed != '')
            set @result = @changed;
    end;

    return @result;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sn,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL((CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',code)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(code,1,CHARINDEX('-',code,1)-1) ELSE code END),'')='' THEN '0'
        ELSE CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',code)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(code,1,CHARINDEX('-',code,1)-1) ELSE code END
    END AS Code,
    CASE (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',code)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(code,CHARINDEX('-',code,1)+1,LEN(code)) ELSE 'NA' END)
        WHEN '' THEN 'NA'
        ELSE CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',code)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(code,CHARINDEX('-',code,1)+1,LEN(code)) ELSE 'NA' END
    END AS changed,
    sal
FROM EMP
```

**[SQl Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/383ae/1)**